# Find Controller That Is Installed From a Package

Tags: installation

I Installed **Sitecore Twitter Feed Integration** package from the market place. The module installs a controller called **SitecoreTwitterFeed.Web.Controllers.TwitterController**, which I'm trying to view its code. The code exits on Sitecore and not my solution.

What I'm really trying to do is avoid this error by pointing the controller field to **SitecoreTwitterFeed.Web.Controllers.TwitterController**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SSE. You can decompile the assembly that comes with the module using ILspy or DotPeek and look for the controller code.

Comment: Also, did you try passing the controller with a namespace like SitecoreTwitterFeed.Web.Controllers.TwitterController, <Assembly_Name>

Comment: Since the Twitter action exists in both SitecoreTwitterFeed.Web and Sitecore.XA.Feature.Social dlls you need to specify the fully qualified namespace in your Controller field

Comment: I tried passing SitecoreTwitterFeed.Web.Controllers.TwitterController, SitecoreTwitterFeed.Web.dll and it worked!

Comment: That's great. I'd add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens when there is more than one DLL with the same controller name in the application. Then the conflict will arise because the `DefaultControllerFactory` would not know which controller to create. For example in your case, *Twitter* action exists in both assemblies:

- Sitecore.XA.Feature.Social
- SitecoreTwitterFeed.Web

In order to resolve this issue, you need to pass the fully qualified namespace of the controller along with the assembly name in the controller field of rendering as shown below:

```
SitecoreTwitterFeed.Web.Controllers.TwitterController, SitecoreTwitterFeed.Web
```